# Get exit code from Python script with redirected output

Tags: unix, python-3.x, ksh

In Korn shell, I have a call to a python program and I am logging everything to $workfile:

```
python3 crontab_search.py | tee $workfile
```

In Python Program crontab_search.py, I am exiting with a returncode:

```
sys.exit(1)
```

If I remove the tee, I get the correct returncode, but I am unable to get the code with the tee.

This works:

```
python3 crontab_search.py; echo $? | tee $workfile
```

But this does not work:

```
python3 crontab_search.py; returncode=$? | tee $workfile
```

I want to do some additional things based on the value of returncode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not a Korn-shell expert, but the pipefail solution from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another#73180) should work in ksh, too. (And the separate execution one as well, obviously.)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. There was alot on that page. I am working in Korn shell on Solaris and pipefail is not supported. I did get this to work: returncode=$( { { python3 ./crontab_search.py; echo $? >&3; } | { tee ./$workfile >/dev/null; } } 3>&1 ) Thanks!